# UpdateView Doesn't Save Data, returns object field data in url

Tags: python, html, django, forms, modelform

Can't find out why UpdateView in django wasn't saving form data upon being saved. Instead, it saved the data in a url when it redirected me back to an un-edited object detail view.

I'm sharing the same template for CreateView and UpdateView

Here's my Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import View

from .models import Blog
from .forms import BlogForm

from django.views.generic import (
  CreateView,
  ListView,
  DetailView,
  UpdateView,
  DeleteView
)
class BlogListView(ListView):
  template_name = 'blogtemplates/blogs.html'
  queryset = Blog.objects.all()
  model = Blog
  paginate_by = 4

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['object_list'] = Blog.objects.all()
    return context

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Blog
  template_name = 'blogview.html'
  queryset = Blog.objects.all()

  def get_object(self):
    id_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
    return get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id_)

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['object_list'] = Blog.objects.all()
    return context

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
  template_name = 'blogpost.html'
  form_class = BlogForm
  queryset = Blog.objects.all()

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['object_list'] = Blog.objects.all()
    return context

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
  template_name = 'blogpost.html'
  form_class = BlogForm

  def get_object(self):
    id_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
    return get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id_)
  
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['object'] = self.get_object()
    context['object_list'] = Blog.objects.all()
    print(context['object'])
    return context
```

Here's my urls.py (in-app urls.py)

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
  BlogListView, 
  BlogCreateView,
  BlogDetailView, 
  BlogUpdateView, 
  #BlogDeleteView
  )
app_name = 'blogs'
urlpatterns = [
  path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog-list'),
  path('<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="blog-detail"),
  path('post/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name="blogs-post"),
  path('<int:pk>/update', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='blogs-update')
  #path('<int:pk>/delete', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name="blog-delete"),
]
```

Here's The HTML Template that is rendered
blogpost.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if request.user.username == 'Thorba' %}
  <div class="container-fluid bg-5 text-center">
  {% if "update" in request.get_full_path %}
    <form action="." method="PUT">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
  {% else %}
    <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
 </div>
{% else %}
  <div class="container-fluid bg-5 text-center">
    <h1 class="box li">Permission Denied</h1>
  </div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the GET request I get after hitting Save on the UpdateView

```
HTTP GET /11/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=F4syRqsTW8X8JtPPSpzpu6qsCf7lryMOlGAnqHFelFt2XuzWCVQaeHEeoINOLnvR&title=And+Yet+%E2%80%A6+Another+Blog&description=POST+METHOD+CHECK&blog=After+a+LOT+of+research+about+UpdateView%2C+I+still+haven%27t+found+a+way+to+SAVE+THE+DATA.+The+url+is+routing+the+UpdateView+correctly+but+after+hitting+save+it+redirects+me+to+the+same%2C+previous%2C+unedited+object+First+Edit 200 [0.01, 192.168.29.226:51360]
```

Here, the 'first+edit' in the get request is what I had tried to save in the UpdateView form but instead went into the url and the object came out unchanged.

How do I Save the edits I make to the blog after I save it?

Answer (score 0):

in your form the value of `method="PUT"` is not valid, see [method attribute docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method), so it fallbacks to `method="GET"`, which is why you are getting GET request after hitting save, and `UpdateView` does not save any data when it's dispatching `GET` request.

To fix this, change `method` value in your form to `POST`.

Then you have to change the logic of form. Don't use things like `{% if "update" in request.get_full_path %}` it seems like an ureliable hack - if you'd change the path in your `urls.py` this will stop working. Or if someone would put `?update=foolyou` into the url arbitrarily, it will also misbehave. Rather than that you should rely on abesnce/presence of `object` in your template context, ie. something like this:

```
{% if object %} # existing object, do update

<form action="{% url "blogs-update" pk=object.pk %}" method="POST">

{% else %} # object not present, creating new one

<form action="." method="POST">

{%e endif %}
```

Comment: I tried that: it gives me an HTTP 405 error saying that the POST method isn't allowed

Comment: This is what it says exactly in the logs: Method Not Allowed (POST): /11/
Method Not Allowed: /11/

Comment: `/11/` resolves as url for `BlogDetailView`, so change the value of form's "action" to the url it needs point to. `BlogDetailView` isnt it.